# What is happening with voltage on capacitor?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Capacitor is fully charged and switch is closed. What is the value of voltage on capacitor (\$U_c\$)?

1. Example

   [image]

\$U_c=0\textrm{ V}\$. I understand this on this way: capacitor is fully charged, and there is no current. So \$U=R\cdot I\$ is giving us always \$0\$ because \$I=0\$.

Voltage on \$R1\$ is \$ U1=R1\cdot I\$.

2. Example

   [image]

\$U_c=R1\cdot I1\$.

Voltage on \$R1\$ is \$U1=R1\cdot I1\$.

I am confused now. Why now voltage on capacitor is not 0 either, if capacitor is fully charged(and current is 0).

- What is the difference between these two circuits?
- Can someone explain me this a simple as possible?

Comment: This looks like homework so we won't solve it but will give you some pointers. (Q1) What is the voltage on R1? (Q2) What is the voltage on R1? Put the answers (showing the method) **in your question** and not in the comments. By the way, you should save the CircuitLab schematics directly into your posts so you can edit them later. You don't need to take screengrabs.

Comment: Given your earlier question, together with the way you analyze the first circuit above (appreciated), I despair a bit that any explanation will help much. (Both are clearly homework, as well.)

Comment: I think you need to go back and think about the basics:  what does "the capacitor is fully charged" mean?  Can a capacitor have voltage without current flowing?  What is the equation relating voltage and capacitance for a capacitor (what is "ohms law" for capacitors).  What happens when current reaches a node?

Comment: @Transistor I answered on your questions. It is homework, I have solutions but I dont understand it.

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic: Andrew's comments are a bit cryptic! (Q1) Close the switch. Now what voltage will C charge to? (Q2) Notice that the part before SW is exactly the same as Q1. C will charge to the same voltage. Now what happens when SW is closed?

Comment: @AndrewSpott
1.Capacitor is fully charged -> Current is 0, voltage is continuous.
2.Capacitor can have voltage without current flowing.
3.I am not sure, do you mean the formuly 1/C with integral or not?
4. Kirchhoff's First Law
Is this correct?

Comment: @Transistor
In my examples switch is already closed and capacitors are fully charged and in that time I need voltage on capacitor. (I forgot to write that switch is closed, but I edited post).


Anyway, when switch is closed(and before was open), current will flow and capacitor will charge?

Comment: 1) "Voltage is continuous"  can you explain what you mean by this?  2)  Correct, a capacitor can have voltage without current flowing.  If this is the case, what is the voltage of a "fully charged capacitor". 3) There are roughly three forms: one that relates current to voltage, one that relates charge to voltage and one that relates the change in voltage to the current.  You should know, and think about, all three.  4) Maybe, I don't know which one is the first law or which one is the second, why don't you tell me what it is in your own words.

Comment: @AndrewSpott
1) Voltage need some time to be changed. Example: Closed switch: U(t-)=15V. After switch is closed capacitor will have the same voltage for some time U(t+)=15V. Later it will be changed.
3)Not sure about this one.
4)The sum of current flowing in one node is equal to the sum of current that is going out.

Comment: @jonk I dont understand your comment? What is wrong with the way I analyze 1. circuit?

Comment: Jonk was referring to the fact that there are some fundamental misunderstandings about capacitors that you have, and those are showing in your analysis of circuit 1.  That is why I am asking these questions.  I am on my phone for a bit, but you should check out the Wikipedia page on capacitors and see if you can answer question 3 for me.  Also, does anyone know how to move this to chat?

Comment: @Andrew: Yeah. Reading her May question as well as this one just makes the whole process look bleak. There are mental barriers that need to be breached. I'm not saying it can't be done -- I'm sure she can learn this stuff with time and effort -- it's just that it's not going to happen here in a way that is consistent with the business model of this site. That, and it just makes me tired facing the prospects of it. I'd work on it if she were here where I had a white board to use. Oh, well.

Comment: @AndrewSpott 
Sorry, I made mistake about switch. It is opened!

These formulas: 1. C=Q/V 2. C=dQ/dV 3. C=Q(t)/C ?

Comment: The first two are correct, you should look at the third one carefully.  Something doesn't make any sense in it.

Comment: @AndrewSpott I found this formula for current voltage relation: \$ U(t)=\frac{1}{C}\int_{t_{0}}^{t } \ I(\tau)d\tau + U(t_{0})  \$

Comment: Yup, that makes much more sense.  What do these equations tell you about what the voltage is (both the value, and how it is changing), for the capacitor in the first problem?  The capacitor is fully charged, and it isn't connected to anything.

Comment: @jonk:  Yea, a whiteboard would make things easier.  Do you know how to move things to chat?  This isn't really appropriate here...

Comment: @Andrew: No. My experience includes someone offering to chat on a math topic, setting it up, and then never answering me when I got in there; and one case here where someone set it up and we used it just fine. But I didn't set it up and I don't know how he did it. I suppose I could just click on things and watch for whatever disaster takes place when I do that. Hmm. I see a create chat button now.

Comment: @AndrewSpott: That doesn't look at all right. Ones I've seen others create pick up all the nice comment text and place it nicely in the chat room. The thing I'm looking at looks as though I could create a room out of whole cloth. But no indication of a way of tagging it into a comment conversation. Perhaps the question owner has to do that? (Just another thing I'm ignorant about, I guess. No surprises there.)

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44078/what-is-happening-with-voltage-on-capacitor

Can you try this link?

Comment: I've joined that chat... though it is in the mathematics stackexchange??

Answer (score 4):

> Capacitor is fully charged and switch is closed

I'm not sure what you mean be this.  Before the switch is closed, there is no path for current through the capacitor and thus, the voltage on the capacitor must be specified as part of the problem, i.e., *the voltage across the capacitor, just before the switch is closed, is an initial condition that must be specified.*  Stating that the capacitor is fully charged is not meaningful here without further context.

It is true that *if* the initial voltage on the capacitor is \$v_C(0) = IR_1\$, then the capacitor voltage will remain unchanged since, in that case, there will be no current through \$R_2\$ to change the voltage across the capacitor.  Put another way, the initial capacitor voltage equals the DC steady state capacitor voltage for the circuit with the switch closed.

If *this* is what you mean by 'fully charged', then the voltage across the capacitor is constant and equal to \$IR_1\$ and not \$0\mathrm{V}\$.

However, if the initial voltage is \$v_C(0) = 0\mathrm{V}\$, the capacitor is, by definition, *uncharged* and thus, after the switch is closed, will charge towards its steady state value of \$IR_1\$ with time constant \$\tau = (R_1 + R_2)C\$

Comment: . .    +1  for Untangling a very tangled question. And I think will help the OP.